# Keep hitting an error when trying to use export/import in JavaScript using Atom

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export, atom-editor

I'm trying to write an array in one .js that can be exported to another, but when I try to import it into the other.js Atom keeps throwing me back the following error:

> /Users.../GitHub/my-first-advent-of-code-javascript-2020/github/day-01/input-data.js:1
>
> export  const myNumberInput = [1757,
>
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1018:16)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
> at [stdin]:3:18
> at Script.runInThisContext (node:vm:133:18)
> at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:310:38)
> [Finished in 0.451s]

The code to be exported is a basic number based array (it's longer than this but this is the format:
`export const myNumberInput = [1757, 1890, 1750, 1440, 1822, 1957];`

the import code is `import {myNumberInput} from '/Users/.../GitHub/my-first-advent-of-code-javascript-2020/github/day-01/input-data.js';`

I've looked online, but I don't understand why I'm getting this error, I've triple checked my syntax. Is this an Atom thing or an ES6 thing or a Node.JS problem (I hope not the latter, I really don't understand that yet)? I'm still learning and not great at problem solving yet. Thanks!

Comment: ES Modules are not natively supported, you need to have a bundler inbetween, you could have a look at webpack, they probably have simple configurations for what you need, but that would require to use dependencies in your project

Comment: Try adding `'use babel';` at the top of the file. I am pretty sure babel will handle it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I tried for ages but couldn't get babel to work, so ended up going with module.exports/import